# Sherlock Side Navigation Drawer - call openDrawer with back button

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment, slide, drawerlayout

I'm using the Sherlock Side Navigation Drawer implementation and i'd like to open the side menu by clicking on the back button, so i did:

- In the main activity, i overrided the onKeyDown event, and i prepared actions when keycode==KEYCODE_BACK
- I Changed inside MyFragment the visibility of the mDrawerLayout:

  ```
  public static DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  ```
- I Called to the openDrawer method in the main activity:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      switch(keyCode)
      {
          case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

              MyFragment.mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
  ```

The fact is that there was a little sliding movement (very quick), and then back to hide. After that i figured out that there was sliding while i held the back button pressed, but if i released it, the side menu went back again to original hided position.

What am i doing wrong??
Thx in advance.

Comment: Use actioncompat library do not use sherlock any more

Comment: use onbackpress method inside that check drawer is open or not. try it

Comment: I've used onBackPress (deleting super.onBackPressed()) and it works when the drawer is closed, so correctly open the side menu, but when the side menu is shown, onBackPress has no effect....

Comment: Maybe disabling back button when the drawer is opened... 
Thanks Dhawal for your answer!!